# Passing UIImage from one Viewcontroller to other gets nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

I am trying to pass UIImage from one Viewcontroller to another in the same way i have passed NSString but in case of image it is getting nil value in second controller.I have used imagepickercontroller to select image from gallery in first controller.
This is InfoViewcontroller.h-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagepicker;
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIImage *image1;

@end
```

This is InfoViewcontroller.m-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1);
image1=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
//[imgview1 setImage:image1];
[imagepicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tocrop" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toimage"]) {

ThirdViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.image2 =image1;}
}
```

This is ThirdViewController.h-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic)  IBOutlet UIImageView *imgview2;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *image2;
@end
```

This is ThirdViewController.m-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//if(image2==nil) NSLog(@"abab");
[imgview2 setImage:image2];
}
```

Why am I getting nil?

Comment: When are you pushing to second controller, make that you push after selection of image from image picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1);
image1=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
//[imgview1 setImage:image1];
[imagepicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tocrop" sender:self];
}
```

You are performing segue with "ToCrop" where as here you checking to toimage

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toimage"])
```

I think it should be  `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tocrop"])` and also use `self.image1=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];`

Comment: OMG !! I am Blind -_- ..thank you...dont need self though...i already synthesized

Answer (score 1):

My friend your segue identifiers are not the same and there for your code inside the if statement in the prepare for segue is not executed.

try something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1);
    image1=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    //[imgview1 setImage:image1];
    [imagepicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tocrop" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tocrop"]) {

        ThirdViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.image2 =image1;}
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure image1 is not nil  after  initWithData.

2.Check If **ViewDidLoad** execute before **destViewController.image2 =image1（sometimes it will）**